# Tasker: Turn wifi on/off scheduled

Tags: wi-fi, tasker

Looking for a way to turn off my wifi everyday at 9:30 pm.
And turning it back on at 7:00am the next day automatically everyday.
Tried a few profiles, none really worked.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What kind of profiles did you try, I wonder?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what profiles you've tried, but that's one of Tasker's easiest jobs:

**Condition:** *Time* (set start and end time)

**Task:** *Net › WiFi* (set "off")

That's it. At "start time" WiFi will be switched off, and and "end time" the setting is reverted to what it was before the condition matched. If you want to be sure that's always "WiFi on", use an exit-task similar to the described task, just with *Net › WiFi* set to "on".